# Hide/Show UI element vs Add/Remove (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So I'm creating an iOS app that uses Facebook to login. The login screen and home screen is the same (uses the same viewcontroller) and adapts the content if logged in.

What is best to do to adapt the screen when logging in from a security and performance stand point?

For example: should I use removeFromSuperview() and addSubview(view) or ishidden = true/false?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for making login and home screen to use the same viewcontroller?

Comment: Should not bother removing elements from view, simply use `element.isHidden = true // or false`

Comment: The largest reason to remove that view? Complexity - for both coder and user. The largest reason not to? I'm guessing that performance/memory is negligible, and in terms of layout both are equal.

Answer (score 8):

You should simply use the `isHidden` property of the button, because:

- It saves you from some boilerplate code, especially if you use outlets
- `isHidden` can be animated easily:

  ```
  UIView.transition(with: button, duration: 0.4, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {() -> Void in
  button.isHidden = true // or false depending on the need
  }, completion: { _ in })
  ```

  while working with `removeFromSuperview()` is harder:

  ```
   UIView.transition(with: segmentedControl, duration: 0.4, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState, animations: {() -> Void in
          self.segmentedControl.alpha = 0.0
      }, completion: { (_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
          self.segmentedControl.removeFromSuperview()
      })
  ```
- Removing and adding UI elements to the view just adds code and work for the programmer, and messes up byte allocations, when compared to hiding that element

Using the `removeFromSuperview()` or `addSubview()` should only be used when you want to remove the button completely from the superview, and preferably not adding it back again.

Let me know if this helps and if you have advices, please comment!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good to know! I ended up dividing the login screen and home screen into different views anyway since it worked better when logging out to reset to root instead of unhiding/showing UI elements

Answer (score 4):

adding and removing subviews is more expensive computationally when compared to using the `isHidden` property to hide and then unhide the view.

**So which one should we use and when?**

1. **Add/Remove subview**

   You should only add a subview when that the view should remain for the foreseeable future. Equally, you should only remove a view when you think it should be removed for the foreseeable future.
2. **Hide/Show subview**

   You should hide a subview when it is known that the view will need to be brought back in the foreseeable future and vice versa for unhiding.

Comment: oops my bad, Thank you :)